# Oracle query and aggregate function

Tags: oracle

I have table name employee_1 suppose in oracle. If the mobile_no and sim_no is same i want select maximum start_date. I have tried , but no success. Please help
The employee_1 table is below

```
Mobile_No   Sim_NO      Start_Date         End_Date 
1111111111  1111111111  3/10/2017 21:02:44  10/10/2017 21:02:44
1111111111  1111111111  11/10/2017 21:02:44 13/10/2017 21:02:44
1111111111  1111111112  11/10/2017 21:02:44 13/10/2017 21:02:44
1111111111  1111111111  12/10/2017 21:02:44
```

I want to display 2 rows

```
1111111111  1111111111  12/10/2017 21:02:44
1111111111  1111111112  11/10/2017 21:02:44 13/10/2017 21:02:44
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, hopefully, it fulfills your requirement.

```
select mobile_no,sim_no,start_date,end_date from(
select mobile_no,sim_no,start_date,end_date,rank() over(partition by mobile_no,sim_no order by start_date desc) rn from employee_1)s
where rn=1
```

Comment: Just need one more favor from you.. Just wondering if i have anothe table called mobile1 with 2 columns mobile_no and status like below                  
       1111111111 connected
 1111111112 connected                                                              and need to fetch data like same i asked previously but only with matching mobile_no with 2 tables with max(start_date) and 4 columns should be displayed in out from 1st table .. thats the only condition.  Thanks again in advance

Comment: @Mayur, can you create another question with example data and expected output, and put all the tables that involve in your requirement with columns. So that you can get a proper answer. I didn't clearly understand your question. Thanks

Comment: Hi Created one more as u suggested...with title Oracle query aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: Your definition, example data and expected result are not consistent. See that you include in the result the line:

```
1111111111  1111111112  11/10/2017 21:02:44 13/10/2017 21:02:44
```

where the Mobile and SIM numbers are different.

Still, try this:

**EDIT**: `TOP 1` was replaced with `LIMIT 1` (Oracle).

```
SELECT LIMIT 1 Mobine_No , Sim_No , Start_Date , End_Date
  FROM YourTable
 WHERE Mobine_No = Sim_No 
ORDER BY Start_Date DESC ;
```

Alternative:

```
SELECT Mobine_No , Sim_No , MAX(Start_Date) , End_Date
  FROM YourTable
```

Comment: thnx for help but sorry top is not in oracle

Comment: Of course, my mistake. Replace it with `LIMIT 1` (I also changed my answer).